# Language evolution in Ido

Tags: language-change, ido

The [Wikipedia article on Ido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ido_language) states that there have been almost no official changes to the Ido language since 1922. But Ido has a small speech community, and therefore there may be unofficial changes to the language.

How did Ido evolve over the last century?